# VRFConsumerBaseV2, fulfillRandomWords can't transfer ERC721

Tags: solidity, erc-721, chainlink, vrf, chainlink-vrf

I was surprised, I can't call safe transfer in fulfillRandomWords, I didn't find any documentation about that or exception. I did a lot of googled, I've found nothing.
My code is

```
/**
 * Callback function used by VRF Coordinator
 */
function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 requestId, uint256[] memory randomness)
    internal
    override
{
    randomRes = randomness[0];
    uint256 gameId = _requestIdToGameId[requestId];
    Game storage game = _gameIdToGame[gameId];
    game.randomNumber = randomRes;
            _nftContract.safeTransferFrom(  
                game.from, // value exist   
                game.to, // value exist
                197 // hardcoded, it doesn't matter. 
            );
    
    emit RequestRandomnessFulfilledRun(requestId, randomResult);
}
```

My Game contract is ApprovedForAll in Erc721, only fulfillRandomWords crashed when transfer ERC721.
Gas limit is 2500000!!!

The same function in contract work.

```
function testTransfer(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 id
) public {
    _nftContract.safeTransferFrom(from, to, id);
}
```

Comment: What network were you using?
There is a great possibility that it is a network congestion, if it is Goerli

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `TransferFrom` inside the **Callback function fulfillRandomWords**, you must approve the VRFCoordinator.

I did this (example)[https://gist.github.com/solangegueiros/fbc68f39465b8f2dc08433f0f2a6108d] to understand the transaction sender